# Mongodb $nin querying sub-document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is the sample document of my MongoDB:

```
user: {
         _id:1,
         name:'xyz',
         age:12,
         mobile:21321312,
         transaction:[
                         {
                             trans_id:1,
                             prod:'a',
                             purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01"),
                         },
                         {
                             trans_id:2,
                             prod:'b',
                             purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01")
                         },
                         {
                             trans_id:3,
                             prod:'c',
                             purchasedAt:ISODate("2014-11-24")
                         }
                     ]
     }
```

I want to get the users who have purchased product 'a' on date '2015-02-01' but not have purchased the product 'b' or 'c' on same day. So I tried querying:

```
db.user.find({transaction:{$elemMatch:{prod:'a',purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01")}}, transaction:{$elemMatch:{prod:{$nin:['b', 'c']}, purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01")}}})
```

But the query seems to return wrong result. It contains some users who have purchased product 'c' on the same day. So I tried:

```
db.user.find({transaction:{$elemMatch:{prod:{$in:['a'], $nin:['b','c']}, purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01")}}})

db.user.find({$and:[{transaction:{$elemMatch:{prod:'a',purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01")}}}, {transaction:{$elemMatch:{prod:{$nin:['b', 'c']}, purchasedAt:ISODate("2015-02-01")}}}]})
```

But none seems to work. I always get the product with same purchased date which is in $nin part. I have tried other queries also but those are of same kind as above (like querying with dot '.' operator) and are trivial to mention here. Is there any way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.test.find({
    "$and" : [
        { "transaction" : {
            "$elemMatch" : { "prod" : "a", "purchasedAt" : ISODate("2015-02-01") }
        } },
        { "transaction" : { "$not" : {
            "$elemMatch" : { "prod" : "b", "purchasedAt" : ISODate("2015-02-01") }
        } } },
        { "transaction" : { "$not" : {
            "$elemMatch" : { "prod" : "c", "purchasedAt" : ISODate("2015-02-01") }
        } } }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Following two ways you can find out your results

1> Using mongo aggregation

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$user.transaction"
}, {
    "$match": {
    "$and": [{
        "user.transaction.prod": "a"
    }, {
        "user.transaction.prod": {
            "$nin": ["b", "c"]
        }
    }, {
        "user.transaction.purchasedAt": ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00Z")
    }]
    }
}).pretty()
```

2>  Using find with projection

```
    db.collectionName.find({
    "user.transaction.prod": "a",
    "user.transaction.purchasedAt": ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00Z")
    },
    {
    "user.transaction.$": 1
    }).pretty()
```

Comment: But those queries will not eliminate the users who bought 'b' & 'c' on same day. My main concern is to eliminate those users.

Comment: @harshad here already pass `user.transaction.prod` equals to `a` then why you should check or eliminate other `prod` .

Comment: thanks for the help. But aggregation is not an option for me as my DB is huge (~4.5M docs & 30 gb data) & query should be quick. unwinding will not make use of indexes. & ur first query seems to be same as the 2nd query in my question. I want to eliminate other products so that I can know how many users bought only 'a' product.